# routerLinkActive for dynamic routes by default is active Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have two links and url I get dynamically by `ngOnInit`.

```
<li><a [routerLink]="welcomeUrl" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Getting Started</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="dashboardUrl" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Dashboard</a></li>
```

Here is my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getOptions().subscribe((options: Options) => {
            if (options.mode.toLowerCase() === "live") {
                this.dashboardUrl = '/';
                this.welcomeUrl = 'welcome';
            } else {
                this.dataService.getName().subscribe((name: string) => {
                    this.dashboardUrl = name;
                    this.welcomeUrl = name + '/welcome';
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

And routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: 'app/welcome/welcome.module#WelcomeModule' },
    { path: ':name', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: ':name/welcome', loadChildren: 'app/welcome/welcome.module#WelcomeModule' },
];
```

But when I launch app these links are active. They are starting  to work fine after click on link that change url.

May be by default these links (urls) are empty and always active? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all,  writing `[routerLink]` (with the `[ ]`) makes the directive expect an array, so your code should read:

```html
<a [routerLink]="welcomeUrl" routerLinkActive="active">...</a>
```

But I think the problem is due to the async nature of your code: `routerLinkActive` executes *before* `welcomeUrl` is set and it can't do its job.

**Solution #1: Wrap your links with `*ngIf` (quick & dirty)**

Wrap your links with a test to only display them once the variables are set:

```html
<ul *ngIf="welcomeUrl && dashboardUrl">
  <li><a [routerLink]="welcomeUrl" routerLinkActive="active">Getting Started</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="dashboardUrl" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Solution #2: Move the async call (more robust but more work)**

Another option would be to move your async call — `this.dataService.getOptions()` — to a point that gets executed *before* the component containing the routerLinks gets activated.

It's hard to be more specific without knowing how your components are organized, but:

- If the component containing the routerLinks is a **routed component**, you could add a `resolve` param to its route declaration and call `this.dataService.getOptions()` inside the resolve. The resolve would fetch the "mode" and then pass it to the component via `ActivatedRoute.data["mode"]`. See the documentation on Resolve: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#resolve-guard
- If the component containing the routerLinks is a **child component** of another component, you could call `this.dataService.getOptions()` inside the parent and pass the "mode" to the child via an `@Input`.

In both cases, the idea is the same: to figure out the "mode" **before**  activating the component containing the routerLinks, so you can set the `welcomeUrl` and `dashboardUrl` variables *before* `routerLinkActive` is executed.

To test whether the async call is indeed the cause of you problem, try the `*ngIf` solution and see if it works.

Comment: I've fixed and now I don't have any active links, but dashboardUrl ("/") should be active.

Comment: And I think you are not right about syntax. Please, look at this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding I don't see any using as you said.

Comment: You're confusing *property bindings* (the link you sent) with *Angular directives* (e.g. `routerLink`). Binding to a DOM property, e.g. `<img [src]="...">`, is not the same as using an Angular directive. Can you update your question by including your route declarations? I think the confusion comes from what `welcomeUrl` and `dashboardUrl` represent...

Comment: Ahhhhhh. So `welcomeUrl` and `dashboardUrl` are variables... You should have said so, I thought they were actual (string) paths. So, have you tried the last syntax I suggested, wrapping the variable names inside [ ] with no quotes around them, i.e. `<a [routerLink]="[welcomeUrl]">`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried your last variant and have no active links at all.

Comment: When you say "no active links" you mean the `active` class isn't set or the links aren't working? I think the problem is due to the async nature of your code: `routerLinkActive` executes *before* the path variables are set. Can you refactor to move the async code to a resolve? That way, you'd know which URLs to use as soon as the comp is activated, without having to subscribe.

Comment: Links work, but nothing is active. What do you mean by refactor async code to a resolve? Can you send me an example?

Comment: Just for clarification, `routerLink` accepts a string or an array. `[routerLink]="welcomeUrl"` or `routerLink="/someroute/subroute"` is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<li>
  <a [routerLink]="dashboardUrl" routerLinkActive="active"
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true,__change_detection_hack__:dashboardUrl}">
    Dashboard
  </a>
</li>
```

this can help you:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18469